# Php removing rest of the text after a specific character

Tags: php

I have made a seo friendly url works fine but i need to remove something from url like this example

example.com/download/bla-bla-bla/2"?id=1........"

i can get the link with this

```
$getremover = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

so i wanna delete the quote part include ?id with php i have to use get insted of post method because as i have heard google doesnt crawl post method greetings.

Comment: Post the result of: `echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it "manually", you can get only the url part before the `?` using [`explode`](https://php.net/explode) it and retain only the first part:

```
echo $getremover = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]".explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[0];
```

This returns an array containing all part of the string divided by `?`:

```
explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

With `[0]` you get only the first value of the array = the first part of the string before the `?`:

```
explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[0]
```

---

Otherwise, there is a dedicated function to do that: [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

> parse_url — Parse a URL and return its components
>
> ```
> $url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';
>
> var_dump(parse_url($url));
> var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
> var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
> var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
> var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
> var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
> var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
> var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
> var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> array(8) {
>   ["scheme"]=>
>   string(4) "http"
>   ["host"]=>
>   string(8) "hostname"
>   ["port"]=>
>   int(9090)
>   ["user"]=>
>   string(8) "username"
>   ["pass"]=>
>   string(8) "password"
>   ["path"]=>
>   string(5) "/path"
>   ["query"]=>
>   string(9) "arg=value"
>   ["fragment"]=>
>   string(6) "anchor"
> }
> string(4) "http"
> string(8) "username"
> string(8) "password"
> string(8) "hostname"
> int(9090)
> string(5) "/path"
> string(9) "arg=value"
> string(6) "anchor"
> ```

Comment: it shows the link 2 times like example.com/download/name/2example.com/download/name/2

Comment: @EnginYücelen maybe you made something wrong. Post in comments the result of: `echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`

Comment: oh wait it worked

Comment: i will mark it as an answer but it doesnt cause any error in normal url right ? if the url includes ? symbol

Comment: @EnginYücelen see my edit, I inserted some info about `parse_url`

Comment: you made my day thank you i appreciate it